# Help me play the Trumpet

Tags: code-golf, music

The [trumpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trumpet) is a valved aerophone instrument, usually pitched in `B♭`. The sound is made when the player vibrates their lips to displace air inside the instrument. That vibration is acquired by setting one's mouth in a specific way, called the embouchure. Different embouchures, with tighter or looser lips, produce different pitches.

Furthermore, each valve in the trumpet also changes the pitch of the instrument. When depressed, a valve closes a path inside the tubing of the instrument, making the air flow through a longer path, thus lowering the pitch of the original sound. For the purposes of this challenge, we'll consider the standard, `B♭` trumpet, in which the first valve lowers the pitch by a full step, the second lowers the pitch by a half-step, and the third lowers the pitch by one and a half step.

#### The Challenge

Your challenge is to create a program or function that, given two inputs `embouchure` and `valves`, determines the pitch of the note being played.

For the purposes of this challenge, the notes will follow the sequence:

```
B♭, B, C, C♯, D, E♭, E, F, F♯, G, G♯, A.
```

#### Rules

- I/O can be taken/given in any [reasonable method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default?s=6|22.7639) apply.
- You're allowed to use `b` and `#` instead of `♭` and `♯` if you wish to.
- Input for `valves` can be taken as a list of depressed valves (`1, 3`) or a boolean list (`1, 0, 1`).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in each language wins.

#### Test Cases:

`Valves` in these test cases is given as a boolean list, where 0 means depressed and 1 means pressed.

```
Embouchure:    Valves:   Output:
B♭             0 0 0     B♭
B♭             0 1 0     A
B♭             1 0 1     F
C♯             0 0 1     B♭
C♯             1 1 1     G
E♭             1 0 0     C♯
G              0 1 1     E♭
G♯             1 0 0     F♯
G♯             0 0 1     F
G              1 0 0     F
F♯             1 0 0     E
D              1 0 1     A
A              1 1 1     E♭
E              1 1 0     C♯
E              0 0 1     C♯
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm not much of a musician yet, so I do apologize for any butchering I might've made on the test cases. Corrections are appreciated.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15020/74163)

Comment: Percussionist here. Wait wait, that's how you spell embouchure. Always thought it started with an a ;-)

Comment: Some of these test cases don't seem to match the problem. For example, `G#, 1, 1, 0` should be `F`, not `F#`, and `C#, 1, 1, 1` should be `G`, not `F#`.

Comment: @vasilescur you're right. I'll fix those and review any other possible mistakes. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: As someone who's played trumpet a long time, I'm really confused by the Embouchure measurement... For example what is a C# Embouchure?

Comment: @bendl I’m still beginning my studies on the trumpet, so I can’t really tell if those are particularly accurate or not. I tried to gather as much information as possible, and inferred some of that information from what I had available. Does that change whether or not the challenge is viable? If not, I think I’ll leave it as it is. As I said in the disclaimer, I’m not much of a musician yet and apologize for any inaccuracies.

Comment: Should `F# 100` be E not F?

Comment: I don't think it changes the viability, I was just totally confused by the concept.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt yes, thanks!

Comment: @bendl There's no such thing. You can't play a `C#` on a trumpet without pressing down any valves. Just specific notes (`B♭-F-B♭-D-F-A♭-B♭...`), the overtone series of `B♭`. Still, even if it doesn't reflect a real instrument the challenge is perfectly well defined.

Comment: @bendl Same, got confused there

Comment: @bendl playing only on the mouthpiece, sure you can have a C# embouchure. Attach the instrument and it won't work so well, as noted in other comments, unless you play in a high enough octave... :)

Answer (score 4):

## Python <del>3</del> 2, <del>125</del> <del>119</del> 81 bytes

```python
lambda e,f,s,t,n=2*'A G# G F# F E Eb D C# C B Bb'.split():n[n.index(e)+2*f+s+3*t]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NDoIwEITP@hST9NAWKgG9mWDCbx9CPUikkUQLgR706dECarOX/TIzO9nuZW6t3o0qPo33y6O6XlALJQZhhI63Hk0gCSRKghIFigo5MoIMKdKKBkN3bwzje33UQaOv9ZPV3N96yh/8nWfOo2p7mHowaDQYo5@ICO1w8YXoD5FFCxmZbT@I7FgoFtuUkXN@EiRxBTcvHaF0XbnTmLgd8x4u@3yI79errm@0YfYdAbo5UAHFPIucj28)

Saved a lot of bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan.

---

My original solution (in **Python 3**):

```python
n=2*'Bb B C C# D Eb E F F# G G# A'.split()
e,f,s,t=str(input()).split()
print(n[n.index(e,9)-2*int(f)-int(s)-3*int(t)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xDoIwFEV3f6ND3yO3RGByYBAEPsK4EEtsYp4NfSb69VWcnG7OOcONb709pMlZ2rqw3YwOPXqDE4YZA0aMBhMmg6MtU7wHJQvLO48FCdomXSlIfCox//e4BlGSs5RBrv5FHgd2dbHJhd02iV3zY@UL5/x9rrBH9QE)

Saved 6 bytes thanks to @HyperNeutrino.

---

#### Explanation

First, I make an array of notes, but doubled in length so I don't have to worry about looping around from `Bb` to `A`.

Then, I take input in the following format (for example):

```python
Bb 1 0 1
```

I then find the index of the starting note using `n.index(e,9)` (the `9` is there to make sure that I start well in the middle of the (doubled) list. I calculate the desired offset with the expression:

```python
2*int(f) - int(s) - 3*int(t)
```

Where `f` is the first valve, `s` is the second valve, and `t` is the third.

Finally, it simply prints the note found in the list by subtracting the offset from the starting index.

Comment: save a few bytes by separating by spaces. `"<some string>".split()` splits by whitespace by default

Comment: Save 30 bytes by moving to Python 2 (avoiding `str` and `int` casts and allowing evaluated input) and reversing the notes and offsetting forward (avoiding the `,9` in the `index` call. [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##Fcu7CsIwFAbg3af4IUNuh2Lj3MFeH0JciikG5BjMEerTRx2/4csfuT851MpdcPqMRWHBrDBjwrRixKAwoEe/6qbkRxJjD5E2KiRd4vz@O78Si@ELN4lvcTfR@uA2X/zJydXWqn@ZWjpS@wU)

Comment: ...and another 8 moving to function (which works in Python 2 or 3) [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NDoIwEITP@hST9NAWKgG9mWDCbx9CPUikkUQLgR706dECarOX/TIzO9nuZW6t3o0qPo33y6O6XlALJQZhhI63Hk0gCSRKghIFigo5MoIMKdKKBkN3bwzje33UQaOv9ZPV3N96yh/8nWfOo2p7mHowaDQYo5@ICO1w8YXoD5FFCxmZbT@I7FgoFtuUkXN@EiRxBTcvHaF0XbnTmLgd8x4u@3yI79errm@0YfYdAbo5UAHFPIucj28)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I learned several Python golfing tricks from your improvements. Thank you so much!

Comment: ...in fact you can use the list in its original order *without repetition* and subtract values since the negative index never goes out of bounds (the most negative would be `'Bb', 1, 1, 1` taking you to index `-6` which would be `E`, as required) - it's what [TFeld has since done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158317/53748).

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 100 bytes (and 134 for a working trumpet)

```
l="Bb,B,C,C#,D,Eb,E,F,F#,G,G#,A"~StringSplit~",";f=l[[Mod[#&@@#&@@l~Position~#-2#2-#3-3#4-1,12]+1]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9CsIwGEV3n0LyQRdvhrRupVCb/kxCoWPIkKrVQNqKZs6rR0UQhHuWc@DOxt8us/H2ZGJ0BatGVJCQhBrNiAYtWkKHjnBgYfAPu1yHu7M@MLB8KpxSx/WsKCnLDy7069N6uy6BeEopp4xntOcCItU7oXUS@/eFV5NiNcNWfKd1vvl5SX8hvgA)

Quite straightforward.

```
l="Bb,B,C,C#,D,Eb,E,F,F#,G,G#,A"~StringSplit~",";f=EmitSound@SoundNote[l[[Mod[#&@@#&@@l~Position~#-2#2-#3-3#4-1,12]+1]],1,"Trumpet"]&
```

A better output for the cost of 34 bytes.

Comment: Wait ... Mathematica has Audio output??? Wicked!

Comment: Of course Mathematica has a built-in for audio output. This is gold.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>37</s>  36 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ØAḣ7;⁾#b“®JXrẊỤȥ’ṃnŒl$œṗ$Ḋ©i_⁸æ.J¤ị®
```

A dyadic link accepting the valves as a list of `1`s or `0`s as a list representing `[second, first, third]` on the left and the embouchure as a list of characters on the right which returns a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVUAqv9qZWxsef//w5hB4bijNzvigb4jYuKAnMKuSlhy4bqK4bukyKXigJnhuYNuxZJsJMWT4bmXJOG4isKpaV/igbjDpi5KwqThu4vCrv///zAsMSwx/0Ji)**

#### How?

```
ØAḣ7;⁾#b“®JXrẊỤȥ’ṃnŒl$œṗ$Ḋ©i_⁸æ.J¤ị® - Link: list of integers, V; list of characters, E
ØA                                   - yield uppercase alphabet
  ḣ7                                 - head to index 7 = "ABCDEFG"
     ⁾#b                             - literal list of characters = "#b"
    ;                                - concatenate = "ABCDEFG#b"
        “®JXrẊỤȥ’                    - literal integer = 2270857278734171
                 ṃ                   - base decompress (i.e. convert to base 9 using the 'digits' "bABCDEFG#")
                                     -                 = "ABbBCC#DEbEFF#GG#"
                        $            - last two links as a monad:
                     $               -   last two links as a monad:
                   Œl                -     to lower case = "abbbcc#debeff#gg#"
                  n                  -     not equal? (vectorises) = [1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]
                      œṗ             -   partition at truthy indices = [[],"A","Bb","B","C","C#","D","Eb","E","F","F#","G","G#"]
                         Ḋ           - dequeue = ["A","Bb","B","C","C#","D","Eb","E","F","F#","G","G#"]
                          ©          - copy to register and yield
                           i         - first index of E in there
                                 ¤   - nilad followed by links as a nilad:
                             ⁸       -   chain's left argument, V
                                J    -   range of length [1,2,3]
                              æ.     -   dot product (i.e. 1*second + 2*first + 3*third)
                            _        - subtract
                                   ® - recall from register
                                  ị  - index into (1-based and modular)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 71 bytes

```ruby
->e,(b,c,d){a=%w{Bb B C C# D Eb E F F# G G# A};a[a.index(e)-b*2-c-d*3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZLRboIwFIbveYo/bZaoKUS2y8UlgIWHYFxQWjeTDQkic1GfnRWUDnBLGtKer//HKbQ8iO9ms2rsF8VmgmVMzk/p6uHr5Av4CBBQrMEFOEKEFBEiCu/ynMaps82lOs7U3BaLRzuz5eIpuTTFodqDqE/h4LWq049a7QE9fdtV@qmOhcoqJYllxRYQE18QhnjJ0I6EoS0kbIzcG/IIRsjtUm6LQoMC@it0x8IrcjthhyKT4gNh9y6994YiTfo2uhQ3wohOUiEdo@VfHV6Fw5RB4VTIDVoPUu74a3g9uu@QD9DkXLw/Vy9skZU4Ks3eIXc4K1az8qz3FuU2r6DMjOgfScyq/qe@ibUguYft/SgtlcvmBw)

#### 70 chars but 80 bytes

```ruby
->e,(b,c,d){a="B♭BCC♯DE♭EFF♯GG♯A".scan /.\W?/;a[a.index(e)-b*2-c-d*3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZLRboIwFIbveYqTXqkpuG6Xiy6ohUfYBXJR4LiZbEgAicvcg/gQy97JF2Gl2oKwJaQ57df/6ymQ76OPejOr7TnSUURjmow/xYwszqfvxXJ5Pv2suCy558nS9@XgEqeIRQpTZ/38NH0UgXC2aYKHEY7taHJvx3YyeQi/6mxfFkDwPXJgXVbircICQJYvu1KOeMgwLjEhlhVYAIE6kFAI7ig0T0jhshTSPmZX7BLoQaayrIGegc0dWjHrizVmSqywb7L8RqxOVfuv2JdMt6SSvCP2W7HOet3ssK2254u4mzTIG2q5gatOjt2@I1ejv3rlHTi4Jde31NILtEIHRfwKyQ6OSCuaH@XuLN@mJaCpiPzUxMyqf9Y3gRSEQ9j8QbmFaVL/Ag)

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript 96 bytes

Following @vasilescur idea, this is the implementation in js

```
(a,b,c,d,_="B♭,B,C,C♯,D,E♭,E,F,F♯,G,G♯,A".split`,`)=>(l=_.concat(_))[l.indexOf(a,9)-(2*b+c+3*d)]
```

```js
a=(a,b,c,d,_="B♭,B,C,C♯,D,E♭,E,F,F♯,G,G♯,A".split`,`)=>(l=_.concat(_))[l.indexOf(a,9)-(2*b+c+3*d)]
console.log(a('B♭',0,0,0))
console.log(a('B♭',0,1,0))
console.log(a('B♭',1,0,1))
console.log(a('C♯',0,0,1))
console.log(a('C♯',1,1,1))
console.log(a('E♭',1,0,0))
console.log(a('G',0,1,1))
console.log(a('G♯',1,0,0))
console.log(a('G♯',0,0,1))
console.log(a('G',1,0,0))
console.log(a('F♯',1,0,0))
console.log(a('D',1,0,1))
console.log(a('A',1,1,1))
console.log(a('E',1,1,0))
console.log(a('E',0,0,1))
```

Comment: [3 bytes less ;)](https://tio.run/##fY9NCoMwEIX3PYYbEzuK2lUXFvzNsgcoBaNJiyWoqJRexUOU3smL2AalG43MYhg@3pv3HvRJ27wp6s4sK8ZH6o2IQgY5MOydkPC0YOjfEEAI4dB/IIJY3jEkkMibAJHLB81qeM1ph1xstbUouhRSfBFWUTL@Ot9@pkdsItfI9vn@YDB8HfOqbCvBLVHdEUW6/KODLQfjnQI6auhIvIQy9WSrhI6cJYz/tis/yZRmRUZmz3XZVhqilCVbnpGyu6/uNhF7lczxxi8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") BTW the flats and sharps should be counted as 3 bytes aren't they?

Comment: Oh nvm (I didn't see that `b` and `#` are allowed) but you need to use `b` and `#` instead of flats and sharps.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 188 bytes

```
@set n=%1
@set/aC=0,D=2,Eb=3,E=4,F=5,G=7,A=9,Bb=10,B=11,n=(%n:#=+1%+12-%2*2-%3-%4*3)%%12
@for %%n in (C.0 C#.1 D.2 Eb.3 E.4 F.5 F#.6 G.7 G#.8 A.9 Bb.10 B.11)do @if %%~xn==.%n% echo %%~nn
```

Uses `#` and `b`: this means that `Eb` and `Bb` are legal variable names; `#` is handled by doing a string replacement to `+1`. The result of the string replacement is then automatically evaluated and the valves are then taken into account before the result is looked up in a list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
τ┤=Yº○!AÄΔâß₧←╥╟ö'ÄD├æñßf╧å▬tó÷╖
```

[Run and debug it online](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e7b43d59a70921418eff83e19e1bd2c794278e44c391a4e166cf861674a2f6b7&i=[]+%22Bb%22%0A[2]+%22Bb%22%0A[1+3]+%22Bb%22%0A[3]+%22C%23%22%0A[1+2+3]+%22C%23%22%0A[1]+%22Eb%22%0A[2+3]+%22G%22%0A[1]+%22G%23%22%0A[3]+%22G%23%22%0A[1]+%22G%22%0A[1]+%22F%23%22%0A[1+3]+%22D%22%0A[1+2+3]+%22A%22%0A[1+2]+%22E%22%0A[3]+%22E%22&a=1&m=2)

It takes a note name and a list of depressed valves. It builds an array of note names, then calculates the total valve interval, and gets the note at that offset in the array.

```
"AbABbBCC#DEbEFF#G" just a literal
{VA#}(Y             partition at capital letters and store in y
,]I                 get the index of the input note
,2R:t               swap 1s and 2s in valve list
{-F                 subtract valve list from note index
y@                  look up result from note array
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%22AbABbBCC%23DEbEFF%23G%22%09just+a+literal%0A%7BVA%23%7D%28Y++++++++++++%09partition+at+capital+letters+and+store+in+y%0A,]I++++++++++++++++%09get+the+index+of+the+input+note%0A,2R%3At++++++++++++++%09swap+1s+and+2s+in+valve+list%0A%7B-F++++++++++++++++%09subtract+valve+list+from+note+index%0Ay%40+++++++++++++++++%09look+up+result+from+note+array&i=[]+%22Bb%22%0A[2]+%22Bb%22%0A[1+3]+%22Bb%22%0A[3]+%22C%23%22%0A[1+2+3]+%22C%23%22%0A[1]+%22Eb%22%0A[2+3]+%22G%22%0A[1]+%22G%23%22%0A[3]+%22G%23%22%0A[1]+%22G%22%0A[1]+%22F%23%22%0A[1+3]+%22D%22%0A[1+2+3]+%22A%22%0A[1+2]+%22E%22%0A[3]+%22E%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>84</s> 79 bytes

```python
lambda e,a,b,c,s='Bb B C C# D Eb E F F# G G# A'.split():s[s.index(e)-2*a-b-3*c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@7DoIwGIV3n@IkHaCmEIubiQOXtg@hDi1CJFEkwqBPj9ZKuMT82/nac2le3eVeR325P/ZXfTNnjYJpZljO2r2XGCRIkRJkEAYCEpJAQRHEXtg216rz6a49tGFVn4unX9AgWuvABNt1fuqbR1V3KP2Pjcc29igBErNaAO5APNe5JVaXo54SZ8SXRhZwexaoURc/o29ASkagXDCn@AAxcVJk8kOSOdj86aSG95jrcmokRj0bpmG@OR4WLBsJB1zAdIMYCjnQvwE)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>92 86</s> 82 bytes

```c
*r=L"扢bc⍣d扥ef⍦g⍧a",*u;v(z,y,x,w)short*z;{u=wcschr(r,*z);u-=2*y+x+3*w;u+=(u<r)*12;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJNboJAGN1zignGBMYxOrqkNLEtuOkRusERwaRqMwj@xQO48ABu27RdNb0TC69BZxiIgyPp97GYvPe@970BSDsgJMsgtZ/18@F9RNLjx/h8@PQn6fErSI/fno5gbCXGFm3QGq3MKFzQJdxau9hekYiE1KAIbk0rbts9uGmtW324suKWbcR31IS4Z@2zNzqdLw0SehQCfzZaxCT0KQIMBIn3mvhYOvekc9/UdhpglRtMDL0Zgea4eOx70Ixe5jrKFUVJ7qVz6SocK@rE@FdvAtPS9po286Zzg8fpdB7S0w@Qq5s3L07dVuBCMbhF41zAy2X0Y3r6Vfyx7K8ocN68hox2bvmL9XySKYZAiSfGHbFgqC4oHdzCoT6kqy6Qxhnp1rs7jH4CNS@Hv7sBqLl4kdxR@crNHVCTOufFj6qPRjrq8mbfvgLhawhz8AKRhhi8gjDvC@QXg5JXINwlUdBQRap7oIgm6txYyempmQTSrSDlsn32Bw)

Adapted from [@Vazt's implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/158228/help-me-play-the-trumpet/158399#158399).

Answer (score 0):

## Perl6/Rakudo 73 chars

Technically this is 83 bytes because I put the Unicode characters in, but swapping them for the ASCII equivalents would give 73 bytes.

As a `{code block}` with parameters like `$^a` this is a lambda, with a signature `($a, $b, $c, $d)`.

```
{$_=2*$^b+$^c+3*$^d;'AG♯GF♯FEE♭DC♯CBB♭'x 2~~/$^a(\w\W?)**{$_}/~~/\w\W?$/}
```

Call it:

```
say { ... }("D", 1, 0, 1)
>> A
```

Less-golfed:

```
sub f($a, $b, $c, $d) {
   my $totalShift = 2*$b + $c + 3*$d;
   my $doubledScale = 'AG♯GF♯FEE♭DC♯CBB♭' x 2;
   my $matchEmbOnward = $doubledScale ~~ / $^a (\w\W?)**{$totalShift} /;
   my $matchFinalNote = $marchEmbOnward ~~ / \w \W? $ /;
   return $matchFinalNote;
}
```

Here we double a string `'...' x 2` using the `x` infix operator, then searching for the embouchure followed by n notes using the smartmatch operator `'...' ~~ /.../` - the regex hinges on `\w\W?` which is a word char then maybe a non-word char.

We look for n instances of that via `(\w\W?)**{$_}`, where we've already calculated n=`$_` from params `$b` to `$d`. This yields a match from the embouchure note to the resulting note, of which we just want the last so we match that with another `~~ /\w\W?$/`.

The calculation of `$_` first is necessary to permit `$^b` implicit param creation on the block.

### 76 chars

An alternative using an array rather than string matches is 3 more chars:

```
{$_=<B♭ B C C♯ D E♭ E F F♯ G G♯ A>;.[((.first: $^a,:k)-2*$^b-$^c-3*$^d)%12]}
```

Finding the embouchure in the list is achieved with `@arr.first: $^a, :k`, which returns the index (key) of the found element with `:k`.

Setting the array to `$_` (as an object) lets us use `.first` and `.[ ]` on it without spending too many characters.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 155 bytes

```c
char r[][12]={"bb","b","c","c#","d","eb","e","f","f#","g","g#","a"};u;v(z,y,x,w)char*z;{for(;u<12;u++)if(!strcmp(z,r[u]))break;u=u-2*y-x-3*w;u=u<0?12+u:u;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPbboJAEH3nK7YYE1CILL51pY1twY@gPAACmtZLVhdv4UP8iKb/5I/QHS4JCpvOMGSZc@bM7AKhnoRhnocLnyLqei42PesiB4GsyRAhRI/f5jwiyEQ8YgjIJhCw8OWMMJIqZ@2kHbWDCnqDM7nEG6oQNsEmYcOhuoyVp92ehqstJ1KXeaoa0Mj/Isxiujk46Ud9PDjA08R4xeaQPTOS5Vu6XO@VQhFFq2DDwkVENcSTKPW/0wg31mZjPVali4S4FQKxIvd3qD@vLusF9Xefa1krGJU11GvlWrVUvGNTF6XKvyUq8lQiZZK08pdrBUYajd5u1x/UNKNwMIC6GbhiTLtgXBDAHA6/366/LX3c1G8xcOFgMw7bXfple6jkjBlqjVeW22WDWbtBreBUCuIhnXaDRjkHHbG6zeEPJDgcOLspEmy8mtxu43c7t5Fg6gIvP9biBzLA@buXmGWQewB3AxigRwB@P0MEYPBHIKqkWj2SsnerIOmJCkS9E0FBLFKaC3bni/ZQ5o2OfD1Qlv8B)

Simple approach.

Valve input is 0,1.

Embouchure input must be lowercase. Interestingly, TiO is not finding `strcmpi()` without including `string.h`, whereas mingw-gcc allows it with the standard `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` warning.